# ¿Se puede combinar PDO y Msqli?

Tags: php

Soy nuevo aprendiendo a programar en php y me he encontrado con Pdo y Msqli según sus experiencias me podrían ayudar a resolver mi inquietud si ¿se pueden usar cosas tanto de pdo como de msqli sin que causen problemas?, puede que parezca algo tonto pero he investigado y nada me a ayudado a resolver mi inquietud.

Comment: No deberías en realidad. No hace falta tampoco. Si puedes usar siempre PDO, úsalo.

Comment: No existe necesidad de hacer algo así, las 2 por separado son lo suficientemente poderosas para funcionar por si mismas, entonces usa la que mas convenga a tus necesidades

Comment: PDO es una capa de abstracción de las tareas cotidianas en Bases de Datos, lo que "estandariza" el acceso a ellas, casi sin importar de qué tipo se trate. Sin embargo para aprendices recomiendo, usar el driver directo, Mysqli en este caso. Cuando estés claro en el concepto puedes ir con PDO y ya no necesitarás más nada.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigos

Answer (score 2):

Creo que tu pregunta tiene respuesta.

Si por *combinar* entiendes usar PDO y mysqli **en un mismo contexto de consulta**, como sería por ejemplo:

- conectar con PDO
- usar métodos de PDO para unas cosas
- usar métodos de mysqli para otras cosas con la conexión u otro objeto de PDO

**Esto es imposible**, porque PDO y mysqli son dos cosas totalmente difirentes para un mismo fin que es trabajar con la base de datos (MySQL exclusivamente en el caso de mysqli) y varias bases de datos en el caso de PDO.

---

Si por combinar entiendes usar PDO y mysqli cada una en su ámbito, incluso en un mismo código, esto es posible.

Por ejemplo (en un mismo archivo o aplicación):

**Contexto A**:

- crear una conexión con PDO
- consultar con PDO
- leer con métodos de PDO

**Contexto B**:

- crear una conexión con mysqli
- consultar con mysqli
- leer con métodos de mysqli

**Esto es posible**. Otra cosa es que sea factible. Como bien han dicho en comentarios, tanto PDO como mysqli tienen todas las herramientas que necesitas para trabajar con la base de datos. PDO ofrece algunas ventajas con respecto a mysqli, pero no es el tema de la pregunta. Y algunos dicen que mysqli es más rápido, pero eso tampoco es tan fácil de probar y tampoco es el tema de tu pregunta.

En cuanto a esa posibilidad imagina un contexto un poco descabellado, pero esto es posible:

**Contexto Loco 1**

- Conectar con PDO
- Insertar registro con ID=1 en `unaTabla`

Y, justo en la siguiente línea:

**Contexto Loco 2**

- Conectar con mysqli
- Actualizar o borrar registro con ID=1 en `unaTabla`

Esto sería **posible**, porque no estás mezclando en ningún momento código de un contexto en otro.

Comment: Te lo agradezco mucho amigo